# Does anyone know where to fix this error in my python program?

Tags: python

This is one of my first programs in Python and somehow this script won't compile.

```
company_name = "coding temple, inc."
company_address = "283 Franklin St."
company_city = 'Boston, MA'

 #declare ending message
message ="Thanks for shopping with us today!"
#create the a top border
print("*"*50)

print(" \t\t{ }".format(company_name.title()))
print(" \t\t{ }".format(company_address))
print(" \t\t{ }".format(company_city))
```

The interpreter marks "key arguments ' ' has no corresponding argument" in lines 11-13

Comment: Welcome.  Don't prefix line numbers which means it prevents us from easily copy & paste your program for debugging.  Use a comment or just write the issue up.

Comment: remove  space in {}

Comment: Thanks letting me know, I corrected the prefixes

Comment: If you are on python3 a f-string like this would be more concise to say the same thing: f" \t\t{company_name.title()}"

Answer (score -1):

You need to either provide the index of arguement like in the first line of code pasted below. Or preferably use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) like in second line.

```
print(" \t\t{0}".format(company_city))
print(f" \t\t{company_city}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, it is much appreciated

Comment: No problem. Upvote and accept if it helped you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have spaces between your brackets. Just replace `{ }` with `{}` and you should be all set!

Comment: who would've thought a space would make such a difference, thank you for your input

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem!